# About the problem of the number theory.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

When I read a paper about the number theory, I found a problem. However, there was not its proof in the paper, and I can't solve it. I would like someone to help me. The problem is below:
Let $L$ and $r$ be a positive integer and define $Z_L:=\{ 0,1,\ldots L-1\}$ and $Z^*_L:=\{ i\in Z_L\mid gcd(i,L)=1\}$. For $a\in Z^*_L$ and $b\in Z_L$, define $f_{(a,b)}:Z_L\rightarrow Z_L$ as $f_{(a,b)}(x):=ax+b$ (mod $L$). Then, 
$\exists x_0\in Z_L$ s.t. $f^r(x_0)=x_0$ if and only if $gcd(a^r-1,L)$ divides $(a^{r-1}+a^{r-2}+\cdots+a+1)b$. Here, $f^r=f\circ f\circ \cdots \circ f$ (r times) and $f_{(a,b)}^r(x)=a^rx+(a^{r-1}+a^{r-2}+\cdots+a+1)b$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please give us more context, e.g., which paper & what part of it this comes from, what specifically have you tried already to solve this, the part(s) you're having trouble with, etc. Thanks.

Comment: This problem comes from a paper "A Combining Method of Structured LDPC Codes from Affine Permutation Matrices", 2006 (ISIT). I already tried to calculate it in the case of $r=2$ and I saw that the claim is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special instance of the fact that the congruence $ux=v(\mod L)$ has a solution $x$ iff the greatest common divisor of $u$ and $L$ is a divisor of $v$. In your case $u=a^r-1$ and $v=(a^{r-1}+a^{r-2}+\cdots+a+1)b$.

[Here you may find the basics on linear congruences](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence)

**Edit:** $v$ should read as $-(a^{r-1}+a^{r-2}+\cdots+a+1)b$ to fit to the setting of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just substitute $u=a^r-1$ and $v=(a^{r-1}+a^{r-2}+\cdots+a+1)b$, but I got $(a^r-1)x=(a^{r-1}+a^{r-2}+\cdots+a+1)b$ (mod $L$), which is not what I want. Why? This congruence becomes $a^rx-(a^{r-1}+a^{r-2}+\cdots+a+1)b=x$ (mod $L$).

Comment: See my edit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that $a$ divides $b$ if and only if $a$ divides $-b$?

Comment: Yes, $a$ divides $b$ says that there is some $k$ such that  $b=k a$. Thus $-b=(-k) a$, i.e., $a$ divides $-b$. The other part of "iff" is similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I completely understand what I wanted to know.